# Delete MySQL table with an Iterator

Tags: mysql, sql, database, conditional-statements

Is it possible to delete in a while loop like iteration ?
ex:

> id  value
>   1 12
>   1 13 - should delete
>  
>   1 14 - should delete
>   2 15.3
>   2 43 - should delete
>   2 22 - should delete

Now I need to delete every 2nd and 3rd ( i%2==0 || i%3==0 ) rows.

Comment: for every id do you have only three values or you can have more?

Comment: Use some scripting language to build and launch the SQL DELETE.

Comment: @Marco only three values

Comment: You should also check the condition you are using. `( i%2==0 || i%3==0 )` will also lead to the fourth row being deleted. This would be better: `( (i%2==0 && (i+1)%3==0) || i%3==0 )`.

Comment: The terms "2nd" and "3rd" only have meaning if rows are ordered. So, what is your ordering? Is it: `{id, value}`, as your example seems to suggest? *(BTW, if you are using InnoDB, rows are natively ordered by PK, but MyISAM makes no such guarantee.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this after taking a backup:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temptt;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptt (`id` INT, `value` INT);
INSERT INTO temptt 
    SELECT * FROM your_table GROUP BY id;
DELETE t1.* 
FROM your_table t1 LEFT JOIN temptt t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.value = t2.value
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

The idea is to insert data that should not be deleted in a temporary table and then delete all data in your_table that are not in that table.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select * from t;
+------+-------+
| id   | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 |    12 |
|    1 |    13 |
|    1 |    14 |
|    2 |    15 |
|    2 |    43 |
|    2 |    22 |
+------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @c = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete t
    -> from t join (
    ->   select t.*, mod(@c := @c + 1, 3) c
    ->   from t
    ->   order by id, value
    ->   ) t1
    -> on t1.id = t.id
    -> and t1.value = t.value
    -> and t1.c != 1;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from t;
+------+-------+
| id   | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 |    12 |
|    2 |    15 |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If it's not about 3, 4th, but you need one per group:

```
mysql> select * from t;
+------+-------+
| id   | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 |    12 |
|    1 |    13 |
|    1 |    14 |
|    2 |    15 |
|    2 |    43 |
|    2 |    22 |
+------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete t
    -> from t
    -> left join (
    ->   select * from t
    ->   group by id
    ->   ) t1
    -> on t1.id = t.id
    -> and t1.value = t.value
    -> where t1.id is null;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> select * from t;
+------+-------+
| id   | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 |    12 |
|    2 |    15 |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```